# Conditional render works in stateless functional component but not in stateful

Tags: reactjs

I am converting a stateless functional component into a stateful component. Conditional rendering that works fine in the stateless version creates a parsing error in the stateful version.

This code works:

```
const Milestone = ({ milestone }) => (
  <div>
    {milestone.displayProperties.hasIcon
  && <Img src={`https://www.bungie.net${milestone.displayProperties.icon}`} alt="Milestone Icon" />
  }
    <p>{milestone.displayProperties.name}</p>
    <p>{milestone.displayProperties.description}</p>
  </div>
);
```

This code gets me a Parsing error (or various other errors when I've tried other ways to write the "if" statement)

```
  render() {
    const { milestone } = this.props;
    return (
  <div>
    {milestone.displayProperties.hasIcon
  && <Img src={`https://www.bungie.net${milestone.displayProperties.icon}`} alt="Milestone Icon" />
  }
    <p>{milestone.displayProperties.name}</p>
    <p>{milestone.displayProperties.description}</p>
  </div>
    );
  }
```

I've tried writing it with different forms of "if" statements.
The closest I've gotten is with

```
{condition ? <Img /> : null}
```

but it breaks as soon as I add src={`...string literal`}

The Img tag is a styled component.

The above code worked great as a stateless. Even if the answer is a simple rookie mistake, I'd love to know what I'm not grasping about JSX that causes this mistake.

EDIT: This may just be an issue with ESLint? I should've tested the site first, because everything seems to render fine in browser.

Comment: Can you update your code with this part `src={...string literal}`?

Comment: That is the same as in the code I pasted. 
```
src={`https://www.bungie.net${milestone.displayProperties.icon}`}
```

Where the "unexpected token" error occurs seems to change based on whatever I typed last. I went in and changed my props destructuring to try a thing and then the error moved to up there. Leads me to think it is actually an error with my Linter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
<div>
 {
  milestone.displayProperties.hasIcon 
  ? <Img src={`https://www.bungie.net${milestone.displayProperties.icon}`} alt="Milestone Icon" />
  :<span>No Icon found!</span> 
 }
 <p>{milestone.displayProperties.name}</p>
 <p>{milestone.displayProperties.description}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That starts to work until I start adding the src={} attribute. I get Unexpected Token from within the template literal.